# check_mysql_query nagios offset time

Tags: mysql, plugins, nagios

I need to use the **check_mysql_query** nagios plugin to check a field in a table

```
mysql> select TimeStamp from SorterCycleDetails;
+------------+
| TimeStamp  |
+------------+
| 1394278125 | 
+------------+
```

The TimeStamp is the time at which run a process and I'd like to have a **WARNING** if the difference between that value and system time is greater than 12 hours.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think so this question is for mysql topic but around Nagios you need return 1 or 0 , or true or false in the result of your query. This you can get using IF function in your query, using DATEDIFF() or TIMESTAMPDIFF() to rest 12 hours and compare if is greater than 12 with NOW() mysql function too.